# How to pass active storage images to email

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am using active storage in my Rails application. The frontend is on React. I am uploading an image via react uploader and sending that image to the backend API where I am storing it to S3 bucket using active storage.

This is the API that handles the image:

```
            if image.attached?
               opts = ImageUploader.resize_to_fill(blob: image.blob, width: 100)
               variation = ActiveStorage::Variation.new(combine_options: opts)
               variant = ActiveStorage::Variant.new(image.blob, variation)
               return rails_representation_url(variant, only_path: true)
            end
```

This returns the path in the following format:

```
             /rails/active_storage/representations/...../file_name.png
```

This works all fine when I use this path inside the application, but I want to send this image in email, there the image breaks as the src attribute can not read this path. If I append `http://localhost:3000` manually in the email through dev tools, I am able to see the image then.

Weirldy, in the email, I also see the path appended with http by itself like below:

```
             http:/rails/active_storage/representations/...../file_name.png
```

I did a workaround and gave only_path to false. This way I was able to get back the complete URL but in the email I got duplicate http written somehow.

Desired Result:

1. Either the email also appends the host_url along the protocol or removes the http also so that I am able to pass the complete valid URL.
2. If there is a way to alter the api and somehow get the s3 endpoint directly that would really really work but I am not sure how to do so. It would return the url like this: `//{bucketName}/uploads/file/id/image.jpeg`

Any help please!

Comment: There should be a s3 url you can use.

Comment: I have all s3 configured in the environment file but there is no method which calls it directly

Comment: We use carrierwave to handle file uploads (and s3 files) https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave
Try using that.